# How to make a POST request to myjson

Tags: json, reactjs, post

I've created some data in json format at `myjson.com`. I want to start using this data. I understand I need to do `axios.get(url)` to use the data in my code but once I've manipulated that data some way is there a way to POST something back? or do I need to use an actual db?

I don't really want to use a real DB as this will take time to spin up

I tried doing `axios.post(url)` but it just gave me a 404 saying it does not exist. even though I can go to that url

any ideas?

i have an array of products inside my json and I just want to change something in there?

Comment: Do you mean you need to save the updated json back to `myjson.com` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update the same bin, you need to make a PUT request to `/bins/:id`:

```
axios.put('https://api.myjson.com/bins/:id', { /* updated data */ })
```

You'd make a POST request to `/bins` if you wanted to create a new bin:

```
axios.post('https://api.myjson.com/bins', { /* data */ })
```